# Attribute error: None type has no attribute summary in keras

Tags: object, keras, attributes, nonetype

I have tried to go in deep with my understanding of word embedding and NLP in keras implementing and copying part of the code creating a Keras model using functional API. When I launch model.summary I receive an Attribute error: None type has no attribute 'summary'.

After many attempts decreasing the numbers of layers, the dimension of word embedding matrix unfortunately nothing changed. I don't know what to do.

```
def pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec, word_to_index):


    vocab_len = len(word_to_index) + 1                  
    emb_dim = word_to_vec["sole"].shape[0]      
    emb_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len,emb_dim))

    for word, index in word_to_index.items():
        emb_matrix[index, :] = word_to_vec[word]
    print(emb_matrix.shape)

    embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_len,emb_dim,trainable =False)
    embedding_layer.build((None,))


    embedding_layer.set_weights([emb_matrix])

    return embedding_layer
def Chatbot_V1(input_shape, word_to_vec, word_to_index):

    # Define sentence_indices as the input of the graph, it should be of shape input_shape and dtype 'int32' (as it contains indices).
    sentence_indices = Input(input_shape, dtype='int32')

    # Create the embedding layer pretrained with GloVe Vectors (≈1 line)
    embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec, word_to_index)

    embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)   
    # Propagate the embeddings through an LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
    X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(embeddings)

    # Add dropout with a probability of 0.5
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    # Propagate X trough another LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
    # Be careful, the returned output should be a single hidden state, not a batch of sequences.
    X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(X)
    # Add dropout with a probability of 0.5
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    # Propagate X through a Dense layer with softmax activation to get back a batch of vocab_dim dimensional vectors.
    X = Dense(vocab_dim)(X)
    # Add a softmax activation
    preds = Activation('softmax')(X)

    # Create Model instance which converts sentence_indices into X.
    model = Model(sentence_indices, preds)

model = Chatbot_V1((maxLen,), word_to_vec, word_to_index)

model.summary()
```

Launching model.summary:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'

Why? What is wrong in layers definition?

Answer (score 3):

The function `Chatbot_V1` does not return anything, and in python this is signaled by `None` if you assign the return value of the function to a variable. So just use the `return` keyword to return the model at the end of `Chatbot_V1`

Comment: You are completely right, I was looking for something really stranger, instead it was a copy and paste error. Thanks a lot for your help and your time.